# OneDrive API expiration for shared link

Tags: onedrive

I would like to know whether there is any way to share a file using Microsoft OneDrive API with an expiration time(10 days)?
I'm already aware that I can create a share link to the file but how do I set an expiration date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 options

If you are the admin of the site then go to [sharing settings](https://admin.onedrive.com/?v=SharingSettings) and set "Links must expire within this number of days" to 10.

Set a timer and manually remove the sharing link at 10 days.

Setup an automated process (eg cron job) where at 10 days the item(s) is copied, the original is deleted and then the copy is renamed to the original name.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to know if there is any API that allowed me to set an expiration date on the shared link.

Comment: sorry I cannot see it as an option. But I can see it would be useful.